# Asp Net 2.0 - Validators, IE10, and Old Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, internet-explorer-10, jscript

I'm using ASP .NET's RequiredFieldValidators in Internet Explorer 10, and if it matters, the document mode is IE5 Quirks, but the javascript generated by the controls in WebResource.adx is outdated IE10.  It tries to retrieve attributes using something along the lines of

```
element.attribute
```

Instead of the standard

```
element.getAttribute(attributeName)
```

As a result, the code doesn't run successfully due to the undefined values, and validates the controls as true no matter what.

I think the problem may come from the fact that the ASP can't detect IE10 because it's out of its defined browser versions.  And before you say anything, yes, I'm aware of Microsoft's available hotfix, but due to work rules, I can't install it on my machine.

So my questions are as follows:
Will updating the ie.browser definition file fix this problem?
And if so, what changes would I have to do to the file?  (Please keep in mind that I'm  manually change the file.)

It may help to know that asp.net generates webresource.axd from webuivalidation.js, and that the it contains the line

```
Page_ValidationVer = 125;
```

I don't know if that's the latest version.  If not, how could I get the latest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might as well answer my own question.

The reason IE10 couldn't has nothing to do with the browser definition files.  Instead, the problem was caused in the web.config file, where the option xhtmlconformance = true.  (It is automatically set to true when you migrate from asp.net 1.0 to 2.0+)  This option allows the project to continue to run legacy code, at the expense of not producing completely modern code.  As a result, it made the project produce legacy code for the validators that is no longer valid in IE10.  This can be fixed by simply changing the value of xhtmlconformance to false, but be prepared to have your project broken if its not up to date.